# jQuery Cycle2 multiple slideshow nav

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I need to work the first slider with a navigation and the second automatically but click on the navigation buttons run both sliders. Code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('.scrollsingle').cycle('prev');
  jQuery('.scrollsingle ').cycle('next');
});
</script>

<button data-cycle-cmd="prev">Prev</button>
<button data-cycle-cmd="next">Next</button>

<div class="images scrollsingle cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" 
    data-cycle-timeout="4000"
    data-cycle-slides="> div">

   <div>content</div>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content</div>
</div>

<article class="span3 box boxstaff cycle-slideshow" 
    data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz" 
    data-cycle-timeout="2000"
    data-cycle-slides="> div"
    >

   <div>content</div>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content</div>
   <div>content</div>
</article>
```

Comment: Consider marking the answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a class with the name 'cycle-slideshow', you're auto initializing your slideshow and this will treat all containers with that class the same way, like any other class would. What you need to do is manually initialize your slideshow by declaring a different class like this:

```
<div class="slide1">
    <img src="image1.jpg">
    <img src="image2.jpg">
    <img src="image3.jpg">
    <img src="image4.jpg">
</div>

<div class="slide2">
    <img src="image5.jpg">
    <img src="image6.jpg">
    <img src="image7.jpg">
    <img src="image8.jpg">
</div>
```

Then your JQuery code must have these simple lines before you manipulate anything under your custom class for the slidesow:

```
//Initialize slide1
$('.slide1').cycle();

//Initialize slide2
$('.slide2').cycle();
```

After that you can do everything as you would normally do with the cycle-slideshow...
Hope that helps you!

Ex:

```
$('.slide1').cycle('goto', 4);
```